# Unity: How to handle unique events for instances of Prefab

Tags: c#, user-interface, events, unity-game-engine

I am setting up a UI system to help depict my player inventory. I created a Prefab composed of UI Panels, Image component for the icon, and some Text.

I use a UI_InventoryManager class to redraw the slots when the UI is enabled or when the player's inventory changed. However, the slots also have a Button component that I would like to use for event handling.

Here is my setup so far:

- **InventoryManager detects changes -> Redraws UI to include new slots.**
- **When any of the slots are clicked -> Signal an InfoPanel manager to update and redraw an Info Panel with the clicked slot item information.**

Here is the RedrawUI function within the UI_InventoryManager - This function works properly visually speaking. It populates the UI with the items as expected. Please ignore how inefficient it is, I just want the overall interaction to work first:

```
 private void RedrawUI()
    {
        // The ItemSlot prefab to be added to the grid layout.
        Transform slot;

        // The item information we are appending to the slot.
        InventoryItem itemInfo;

        // Image representing item icon. Acquired from InventoryItem metadata.
        Image itemIcon;

        // Text UI to display the item name. Acquired from InventoryItem metadata.
        Text itemName;

        // Text UI to display the item stack count. Acquired from the InventorySlot object in PlayerInventory class.
        Text itemCount;

        ClearUI();

        foreach(KeyValuePair<int, InventorySlot> item in playerInventory.Inventory)
        {
            // Places the Slot UI prefab inside the Group Box for proper layout.
            slot = (GameObject.Instantiate(inventorySlotPrefab, itemGroupBox.transform));

            // Attach an InventoryItem component that will hold the information of the item.
            itemInfo = slot.gameObject.AddComponent<InventoryItem>();

            // Use the ItemFactory to abstract the initialization of the item.
            itemInfo.InitInventoryItem(item.Key);
            itemIcon = slot.transform.GetChild(0).GetComponent<Image>();
            itemName = itemIcon.transform.GetChild(0).GetComponent<Text>();
            itemCount = itemIcon.transform.GetChild(1).GetComponent<Text>();

            itemIcon.sprite = itemInfo.ItemIcon;
            itemName.text = itemInfo.ItemName;
            itemCount.text = item.Value.Amount.ToString();

            // Get the Button script from the instance of the prefab.
            // Handle the button click of each UI slot via the UpdateGUI function of the InfoPanelManager.
            Button button = slot.GetComponent<Button>();
            button.onClick.AddListener(() => { itemInfoPanel.UpdateGUI(itemInfo); });

        }
    }
```

The main focus here is on the last line - I am told that is how you subscribe -- or add a listener to an event. In this case the button click. The ItemInfoPanel manager handles the UpdateGUI function as follows:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Update GUI:
    /// Triggered when an Item Slot from the UI_Inventory Manager gets selected.
    /// Redraws the Info panel and populates it with information from the newly selected item.
    /// </summary>
    public void UpdateGUI(InventoryItem _inventoryItem)
    {
        Debug.Log("Entered UpdateGUI");
        // Set the passed item to be our currently selected item.
        _selectedItem = _inventoryItem;

        if (_inventoryItem != null)
        {
            itemIconSlot.sprite = _inventoryItem.ItemIcon;
            itemName.text = _inventoryItem.ItemName;
            itemDescription.text = _inventoryItem.ItemDescription;

            if (ItemFactory.IsPlaceableItem(_inventoryItem.GetItemID()))
            {
                placeButton.enabled = true;
            }
            else
            {
                placeButton.enabled = false;
            }
        }
    }
```

**Results:**

The click event works for the first item I select any item in my inventory. However, when I click again, or click on any different item slot - the UpdateGUI function is not called. I placed the Debug.Log to check; it never made it there. What am I overlooking in setting up this messaging system?

I initially thought that maybe all instances of the prefab will "share" the event handling code. Maybe when I set it for one instance, it does so for all others. That is, the events are not unique to each slot. I am unable to confirm that. I tried using the following method hoping that is the case:

```
                // Places the Slot UI prefab inside the Group Box for proper layout.
            slot = (GameObject.Instantiate(inventorySlotPrefab, itemGroupBox.transform));
            UnityEditor.PrefabUtility.DisconnectPrefabInstance(slot);
```

That had no effect - I am kinda clueless as to this works now, any tips?

**EDIT**
Upon further inspection, I noticed that the item description that appears on the Info Panel is wrong anyways. It seems to display the information of the FIRST ITEM added to the inventory. From there, no matter which slot is clicked, the first item info will appear. This makes me further believe it's a problem with using Prefabs -- shared resources.

Comment: Can you confirm if the reaction is the same no matter which button you click? i.e. only the listener added to the last button persists

Comment: @ryeMoss The event is fired only once. I only see the Debug message once even if I click on the same button. I also noticed that the item description that appears is for the wrong item too -- See my edit above.

Comment: Could there be something not shown here that is disabling the clicking for the buttons? Even if they are sharing resources, I don't see anything above that would keep you from clicking the same button twice at the very least.